# La phrase « le pic de cette 45e vague de chaleur recensée en France depuis 1947 » est-elle complète et claire ?

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe, participe-passé, ellipse

> Nul n’est plus à l’abri : le pic de cette 45e vague de chaleur
> **recensée** en France depuis 1947 a touché lundi toute la façade ouest,
> des Landes et du Gers jusqu’au Finistère. ([LeMonde](https://www.lemonde.fr/planete/article/2022/07/19/la-canicule-se-decale-a-l-est-le-vent-inquiete-en-gironde_6135303_3244.html), je souligne)

J'ai une hésitation à la lecture parce que strictement parlant cette 45e vague n'est pas recensée depuis 1947 si elle se produit maintenant, ce sont les vagues successives qui le sont, alors soit on dit qu'il s'agit de la 45e vague depuis 1947 ou qu'on recense la température depuis 1947 (peu probable, sans doute depuis bien plus longtemps)...

> le pic de cette vague de chaleur, la 45e (qui est) recensée en France depuis
> 1947, a touché lundi toute la façade ouest, des Landes et du Gers
> jusqu’au Finistère.
>
> le pic de cette 45e vague de chaleur, la pire que la France ait connu
> depuis 1947, a touché lundi toute la façade ouest, des Landes et du
> Gers jusqu’au Finistère.

Laquelle de ces deux formulations représente le plus ce qu'on dit et peut-on m'expliquer la syntaxe de la phrase : est-elle incomplète, fallait-il « à être (recensée) » ; le participe passé suffit-il a rendre la phrase heureuse avec la désignation spécifique de la 45e en complément du nom *pic* et la réduction du pronom relatif sans incise ?

Answer (score 1):

> [...] le pic de cette vague de chaleur, la 45<sup>e</sup> (**à être**) recensée en France depuis 1947, a touché lundi toute la façade ouest, des Landes et du Gers jusqu’au Finistère.

La phrase ne précise pas qu'il s'agit de la pire donc ta deuxième proposition est écartée.

C'est bien *à être* qu'il faut comprendre mais il n'était pas pour moi nécessaire de l'écrire, ça peut être simplement sous-entendu.

On n'implique pas que les températures n'étaient pas collectées avant 1947. On indique seulement le nombre de vagues de chaleur observées depuis cette date.